# Cant run compiled kernel on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-kernel

I've just build goldfish both 3.10 and 3.18 kernel like described in:
https://gist.github.com/yan12125/78a9004acb1bed5faf2ffd442163e2ef

I use Ububtu 14.4 and x86_64-linux-android-4.9 toolchain

Now I'm trying to run it using

```
emulator -gpu off -avd arch -kernel /pathto/goldfish/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -show-kernel
```

I use Android 7 api 24 intel 64 emulator, and I get the next messages constantly:

```
[   66.064725] zygote64[2377]: segfault at 7fff096de000 ip 000071a44f2053c0 sp 00007fff096fb770 error 4 in libart.so[71a44ed0c000+6de000]
[   66.280135] init: Service 'zygote' (pid 2377) killed by signal 11
[   66.283398] init: Service 'zygote' (pid 2377) killing any children in process group
[   66.287764] init: write_file: Unable to open '/sys/android_power/request_state': No such file or directory
[   66.293924] init: write_file: Unable to write to '/sys/power/state': Invalid argument
[   66.298796] init: Service 'audioserver' is being killed...
[   66.304149] init: Service 'cameraserver' is being killed...
[   66.311922] init: Service 'media' is being killed...
[   66.322679] init: Service 'netd' is being killed...
[   66.326326] init: Service 'audioserver' (pid 2378) killed by signal 9
[   66.331443] init: Service 'audioserver' (pid 2378) killing any children in process group
[   66.442503] init: Service 'cameraserver' (pid 2379) killed by signal 9
[   66.442513] init: Service 'cameraserver' (pid 2379) killing any children in process group
[   66.442687] init: Service 'media' (pid 2380) killed by signal 9
[   66.442695] init: Service 'media' (pid 2380) killing any children in process group
[   66.442819] init: Service 'netd' (pid 2381) killed by signal 9
[   66.442827] init: Service 'netd' (pid 2381) killing any children in process group
[   66.442942] init: Untracked pid 2501 exited with status 0
```

Any idea how can it be fixed?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same issue - yet no solution. On **[MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ec59d5e4-5fe5-4391-826f-a7964584869e/problem-with-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-api23-marshmallow?forum=visualstudiogeneral)**, there is also a thread about that ("unable to open /sys/...") without solution. But maybe if we follow and see if someone resolves it, we'll be lucky in the end.